# How much should a Work-At-Home privilege make up for poor salary?

Tags: work-environment, salary

I currently benefit from Work-At-Home privilege at my job, but the salary is not very good.

What would you value this privilege in term of salary?
For instance does it worth the trouble to move to a standard job to earn let's say 10k or 15k more?

Thanks

Comment: This isn't an answerable question-- it's entirely dependent on you.  For you, is working from home worth the lower salary?  It doesn't matter if 99% of the world would say "yes" or "no" for themselves, the only thing that matters is your opinion.

Comment: I am voting to close this question as the OP is soliciting an answer that is totally based on the individual's circumstances and therefore subjective.

Comment: Should I delete my answer then?

Comment: @Areks You should edit your question so that its answer is an actionable item. The way you have your question phrased, someone who lives single in the boondocks and who is a primary care give for a sick relative would be glad to work from home and take the 10K to 15K loss in foregone income. Whereas somebody who lives in a big city and can get another job within walking distance of their home would not put up with that income loss differential. And that's just two of a zillion possible scenarios. It's impossible to give an answer that covers each scenario and we simply are not going to do that

Comment: OK, this site made it clear I'm terrible at making questions and that I have no talent whatsoever, but isn't this thread useful as it sheds light on how to perceive the problem correctly? I mean, I now know better how to think about this.

Comment: Olograph, welcome to The Workplace SE. As a Q&A site, we're looking for reasonably scoped questions about real, actual problems you're facing in the workplace. If you can edit this to be about a problem that can be answered with facts and references, the edits will bump the post to the top of the page, where the community can [review and vote to reopen](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/review)

Comment: @Olograph yes, these comments are temporarily useful. You can use them to edit your question into something that can be answered.

Comment: @Olograph: as an example as to why this would totally depend upon you; consider someone making a multi-million dollar salary, someone who wants to travel and work at the same time (I recall one developer working while biking around the world), someone who needs a life saving operation that cost 15k...any question of the form "is it worth it it to" has the answer "Worth it to who? To one person the answer will be yes, to another the answer will be no, only you can decide if it is worth it to you."

Answer (score 3):

This is something only you can answer. We can say lots of things, but at the end of the day, they might not apply to you.

The real question would be **how much *you* value working at home?** Since you call it a privilege, I assume you actually prefer working from home, so let's take a look at other aspects: Are you able to do things that otherwise you wouldn't be able to? Does it allows you to make better use of your time? (Provided that you can actually work based on goals rather than a defined and non-flexible schedule).

For example: If *I* had the option to work from home I would first evaluate how much I'm earning. Is it enough? Does it allow me to find another extra income? Or perhaps I can be more time with my family? Am I happier working and thus more productive? Being a software developer myself, I could find another way to make more money if I could make better use of my time. Does that apply to you? Keep in mind that "enough", as always, is up to you. Are you earning enough for it to be considered a financially sustainable job? Are you happy with it?

Once you have all that on the table, make yourself the very question you asked here: "Would it be worth it to lose the benefits I currently have for an extra 15k a year?"

Comment: Thank you for opening my mind to these considerations. That's what I was looking for, didn't know at the time how to formulate the question.